# Como enviar múltiplos dados diferentes por email?

Tags: php

Boa noite,

E o seguinte eu tenho um sistema com 3 `input` e tenho um `jquery` que me adiciona mais 3 iguais caso queria enviar mais dados eu estou a conseguir enviar por email os dados das primeiras três mas quando adiciono mais 3 já não me envia o valor das 3 que ele adicionou.

**Formulário**

```
<table id="add_estabelecimento_table" border="0" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px; "><input placeholder="País" type="text"  name="input_anuncia[]"></div>  
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px; "><input placeholder="Nome do Estabelecimento" type="text" name="input_anuncia[]"></div> 
        </td>
        <td valign="top" >
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px;"><input placeholder="Localização" type="text" name="input_anuncia[]"></div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Código onde trato o valor do post**

```
foreach ($_REQUEST['input_anuncia'] as $dados_local ) {

  $mostra_dados_local = '
     <div class="movableContent">
        <table width="580" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
          <tr><td height="40"></td></tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #EEEEEE; border-radius:6px;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px">
              <table width="480" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr><td height="25"></td></tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable">
                      <div class="contentEditable" style="text-align: center;">
                        <h2 style="font-size: 20px;">Dados do Estabelecimento</h2>
                        <br>
                           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                  <div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; float:left;">País:</div>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top">
                                  <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_anuncia'][0].'</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top">
                                  <div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; float:left;">Nome do Estabelecimento:</div>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top">
                                  <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_anuncia'][1].'</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top"> 
                                  <div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; float:left;">Localização</div>
                                </td>
                                <td valign="top">
                                  <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_anuncia'][2].'</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td height="24"></td></tr>
              </table>
             </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>   
  ';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, convém mudar um pouco o formulário para facilitar as coisas:

```
<table id="add_estabelecimento_table" border="0" style="margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px; "><input placeholder="País" type="text"  name="input_pais[]"></div>  
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px; "><input placeholder="Nome do Estabelecimento" type="text" name="input_nome[]"></div> 
        </td>
        <td valign="top" >
            <div style="margin:0px 20px 0px 0px; width: 267px;"><input placeholder="Localização" type="text" name="input_local[]"></div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notar que mudei o nome dos inputs, para saber o que é o que (dava para manter igual, mas teria que multiplicar tudo por 3 para usar os campos certos)

Aí, na parte que processa os dados você ajusta o loop nesta parte:

```
$qtd = count( $_REQUEST['input_pais'] );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $qtd ; $i++ ) {
```

e aqui muda as variáveis e põe os índices:

```
                            <td valign="top">
                              <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_pais'][$i].'</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; float:left;">Nome do Estabelecimento:</div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_nome'][$i].'</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top"> 
                              <div style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; float:left;">Localização</div>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top">
                              <p>'.$_REQUEST['input_local'][$i].'</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

Assim, o código será repetido para a quantidade certa de dados do form.

IMPORTANTE: Não quis deixar muito confusa a resposta, mas você pode simplificar muito esse seu HTML, e repetir apenas a parte dos TR, em vez da div inteira. Procure entender e fazer funcionar até esta parte, mas depois tente otimizar o código.